# Is homogeneity preserved under change of measure?

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-volatility, numeraire

In a [paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=51492b844b9066d69c8566aa13425a035a0d8260), Joshi proves that the call (or put) price function is homogeneous of degree 1 if the density of the terminal stock price is a function of $S_T/S_t$. In the paper I think Joshi is silently working under the $\mathbb Q$ measure. What happens to homogeneity, or equivalently the density, if we change measure to for example the share measure. Will it still be a function of $S_T/S_t$ (under the share measure)?

Recall that homogeneous of degree 1 means that $\lambda C(S_t,K) = C(\lambda S_T, \lambda K)$ where $C$ is the risk-neutral measure price and $\lambda > 0$. If the price of  call option under the share measure is denoted by $\tilde C(S_t,K)$ then my question is does $\lambda \tilde C(S_t,K) = \tilde C(\lambda S_T, \lambda K)$ also hold?

Let's consider stochastic volatility models only, as local vol models are hardly if ever homogeneous.

**EDIT:**
I think the answer is yes, but an extra pair of eyes looking at it won't hurt:

So let $\Phi \left(\frac{S}{S_t} \right)$ be the denisty of the (log) price under $\mathbb Q$. Then, following Joshi's proof (Theorem 2.1) in the paper,
$$
\tilde C(S_t,K) = \int (S - K)_+ \frac{S}{S_t} \Phi \left(\frac{S}{S_t} \right) \frac{dS}{S}
$$
So
\begin{align}
\tilde C(\lambda S_t,\lambda K) &= \int (S - \lambda K)_+ \frac{S}{ \lambda S_t} \Phi \left(\frac{S}{\lambda S_t} \right) \frac{dS}{S} \\
&= \int (\lambda S' - \lambda K)_+ \frac{\lambda S'}{ \lambda S_t} \Phi \left(\frac{\lambda S'}{\lambda S_t} \right) \frac{d \lambda S'}{\lambda S'} \\
&= \int \lambda ( S' - K)_+ \frac{ S'}{ S_t} \Phi \left(\frac{ S'}{ S_t} \right) \frac{d S'}{S'} \\
&= \lambda \tilde C(S_t,K)
\end{align}
where the change of variable $S = \lambda S'$ has been performed.

Is this correct? Did I miss something?

Comment: I find the question a bit confusing. Homogeneity is a property of functions. Like the BS option price function is homogeneous of degree one. What would measure change mean in this context?

Comment: @fes For a while I thought homogeneity was only a property of the payoff until I read Joshi's paper some years ago where he shows that homogeneity is also determined by the form of the density. So for example the payoff of a call / put option is homogeneous, but it doesn't mean that the price function is homogeneous: for example under Bachelier dynamics it isn't homegeneous of degree 1 as defined above, but it is homogeneous of degree 1 under Black-Scholes dynamics.

Comment: @fes continued: so yes, the BS call price formula is homogeneous always. But it doesn't mean the model/market price is homogeneous even though you equate the two (via implied vol). So I was wondering if the SV model price of a call / put option price under the share measure retains homogeneity given that the SV model price under the pricing measure is homogeneous.

Comment: @fes One more thing, the BS call price formula in the presence of skew is actually not always homogeneous: it is only homogeneous of degree 1 if the IV is homogeneous of degree 0 (i.e. IV only depends on moneyness, and possibly instantaneous vol)

Comment: I know that option prices depend also on the stochastic process and hence this affects the homogeneity properties of the resulting price functions. But I still don't understand how a function could be homogenous under some measure and not under some or what this measure change even means in this context.

Comment: @fes part I of your confusion: that's exactly what I'm just trying to confirm (ie not affected by change of measure). I did not find that as obvious as you do. As for what it means, for one thing it means that the homogeneity of the smile is not affected either plus potentially some other uses.

Comment: For instance the function $f(x)=x$ is homogeneous of degree one. What is a measure change in this context?

Comment: Also note that current option prices cannot be different under different equivalent measures. Only their expected future evolutions can be different.

Comment: @fes $\tilde C = E^{\mathbb S}_t [ (S_T - K)_+]$, and $C =  E^{\mathbb Q}_t [ (S_T - K)_+]$. They are different, not the same options.

Comment: Ok, I see how you think about it and agree with the above. But note that under the risk neutral measure the call price should equal the expected payoff discounted by the risk free rate. This does not work anymore under some other measure and we should apply some other generally unknown discount rate. But the arbitrage free option price is still the same.

Comment: Like in the BS model, the change to risk neutral measure is used as a trick to derive the BS formula, which under the assumption of GBM is the correct option price. The change of measure does not affect the fact that the BS formula is homogeneous of degree one.

Comment: So if you define the option price as $C(S_t,K)=E^{M}[(S_T-K)_{+}]$, where $M$ is some measure, and ask if the homogeneity of $C(S_t,K)$ depends on the measure $M$, then the answer might be yes. But not sure if you really want to think of it like that.

Comment: @fes As for why I am looking at this, is for barrier options in the presence of skew. I am still struggling with finding a nice approx for it but that's a different topic. I am not entirely convinced the homogeneity is preserved for all $M$. The reason it works under the share measure is because the numeraire change is of the form $S_T/S_t$, but not obvious to me that eg if we choose as numeraire the derivative $E^{\mathbb Q} _t \left[ \exp S_T \right]$, or some other weird numeraire, that homogeneity is preserved.